# Efficiently query missing integers in a range on a field?

Tags: python, mongodb, performance, database

I have a database for a backup service I'm writing [to backup Yahoo! Groups](https://github.com/csaftoiu/yahoo-groups-backup). It incrementally retrieves messages, which have a contiguous numeric id. stored in a `'message_id'` field. So, if the last message on the service is message number 10000, then once the backup is complete, the database should contain 10000 documents, with the sorted `'message_id'`s of each document being equivalent to `range(1, 10000+1)`.

I'd like to write a query yielding the missing message ids. So if I have 9995 documents in the database, and messages 10, 15, 49, 99, and 1043 are missing, it should return `[10, 15, 49, 99, 1043]`.

I've done the following, getting just the ids from the database and running a set intersection in my app code:

```
def missing_message_ids(self):
    """Return the set of the ids of all missing messages.."""
    latest = self.get_latest_message()
    ids = set(range(1, latest['_id']+1))
    present_ids = set(doc['_id'] for doc in self.db.messages.find({}, {'_id': 1}))
    return ids - present_ids
```

This is fine for my purposes, but it seems like it might get too slow for a vast number of messages. This is more for curiosity's sake than a real performance requirement: Is there any more efficient way to do this, perhaps entirely on the database engine?

Answer (score 1):

in SQL word one could use CTE for that, in mongo we can use aggregation with `$lookup` as a kind of CTE (common table expressions)

having this data structure

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("575deea531dcfb59af388e17"),
    "mesId" : 4.0
}, {
    "_id" : ObjectId("575deea531dcfb59af388e18"),
    "mesId" : 6.0
}
```

with missing  `"mesId" : 5.0` we can use this aggregation query, which will project all next expected ids, and join on them. The limitation here is if we have missing more than one message in sequence, but this could be extended by projecting next Id and making $lookup again.

```
var project = {
    $project : {
        _id : 0,
        mesId : 1,
        nextId : {
            $sum : ["$mesId", 1]
        }
    }
}
var lookup = {
    $lookup : {
        from : "claudiu",
        localField : "nextId",
        foreignField : "mesId",
        as : "missing"
    }
}
var match = {
    $match : {
        missing : []
    }
}

db.claudiu.aggregate([project, lookup, match])
```

and output:

```
{
    "mesId" : 4.0,
    "nextId" : 5.0,
    "missing" : []
}
```